# STM32H7 I2S to TLV320DAC32 Setup Issues

Tags: audio, embedded-systems

I designed a board with an STM32H7, an ADC, and a TLV320DAC32. I'm in the stages of just getting a straight audio passthrough working. I am now getting signal output but it's all jumbled, and not at all representative of the input waveform. After lots of reading and messing about, I believe I have the DAC configured correctly, so that leads me to maybe its something with my actual processing loop.

Here is the link to the public github: https://github.com/Psychronic-Audio/DSPDK-Starter

main.c holds the main loop, and the callback for the I2S/DMA double buffering.

audio_processing.c holds the processing loop interacting with the buffers used by the I2S/DMA peripherals

tlv320.c holds the I2C setup code for the DAC chip.

```
//I2S transmit/receive half complete (DMA finished first half of buffer)
void HAL_I2SEx_TxRxHalfCpltCallback(I2S_HandleTypeDef *hi2s){
    inBufPtr = &adcData[0];
    outBufPtr = &dacData[0];

    dataReadyFlag = 1;
}

//I2S transmit/receive complete (DMA reached end of buffer)
void HAL_I2SEx_TxRxCpltCallback(I2S_HandleTypeDef *hi2s){
    inBufPtr = &adcData[BUFFER_SIZE];
    outBufPtr = &dacData[BUFFER_SIZE];

    dataReadyFlag = 1;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_I2S1_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_UART8_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  initialize_filters();

  if( SETUP_TLV320(&hi2c1) != 0){
      return 1;
  }

  HAL_I2SEx_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hi2s1, (uint16_t *) dacData, (uint16_t *) adcData, BUFFER_SIZE);
  HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t *) adcControlData, 7);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim3);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      while(dataReadyFlag != 1);
      process_audio(inBufPtr, outBufPtr);
      dataReadyFlag = 0;
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

```
void process_audio(volatile int32_t *inputSamples, volatile int32_t *outputSamples){
    int32_t leftChannel[BUFFER_SIZE/2];
    float leftChannelFloat[BUFFER_SIZE/2];

    //The data collected from the ADC and DAC are still stereo. We need to separate the left channel out of the mix
    for(int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i += 2){
        int index = 0;
        leftChannel[index] = inputSamples[i];
        index += 1;
    }

    //The data collected is in 24-bit signed format on a 32 bit frame, to do DSP we want the data to be in float format from [-1.0, +1.0]
    for(int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE/2; i++){
        leftChannelFloat[i] = INT24_TO_FLOAT * leftChannel[i];
    }

    //Audio passthrough
    for(int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i += 2){
            outputSamples[i] = (int32_t)(FLOAT_TO_INT24 * leftChannelFloat[i/2]);
            outputSamples[i+1] = 0;
    }
}
```

This code is the meat and potatoes of it, I'm suspecting it's in here.
I'm using Left Justified, 24 bit data on 32 bit frame per sample. The master clock is output to both the ADC and DAC as 256 times the sampling frequency, according to CubeIDE its 47743Hz. I setup double buffering, so that while the DMA is taking in and sending data from one half of the buffers, I am processing data on the other half of the buffers. The DAC is wired such that the output signal is HPL/HPLCOM as differential output.

My question's are: Am I doing the double buffering and processing correctly? Am I setting up the DAC correctly?

This may not be the right community, if not, please advise as to what would be the best location for this. Thanks!

Comment: I didn’t fully digest this yet but are you using timers as the DAC and ADC sample clocks?

Comment: Nope, theres an I2S peripheral in the STM32H7 that I'm using. It's generating the bit clock, word clock, and master clock for the I2S bus. ADC and DAC act as slaves. The DMA peripheral is setup to collect data from this I2S peripheral, and store it in a buffer I can access. That's the "adcData" and "dacData" arrays in the code.

Comment: Those typically have a lot more jitter i believe, and jitter is disaster for an ADC and DAC clock as it translates directly to error in the analog signal. In any event something to confirm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to come back and say I found my problem(s). I had the peripheral clocks running much faster than they needed to be, so I scaled them back. I also had an issue where I declared and initialized an index variable inside a loop, when I meant to do so outside the loop. My output now follows the input as intended, albeit with a lot of noise, but that's not a code issue. Thanks @Dan Boschen for pointing me to the clocks.